# How does jekyll run as a .exe, and it starts rails server also?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jekyll

How does the jekyll gem work, it somehow creates a command line arguement and also runs rails server on port 4000.

Where in the code does it implement this functionality?

https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/tree/master/lib/jekyll

Comment: You should be able to find the code you're looking for here: https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/blob/master/bin/jekyll#L171

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jekyll uses WEBrick. WEBrick also happens to be used by Rails, but is a generic Ruby HTTP server. The functionality is implemented in [`bin/jekyll`](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/blob/master/bin/jekyll).